# What is the function of a curve like a "」"?

Tags: functions, curves

I'm doing curve fitting and the curve look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RhX9.jpg).

I've tried polynomial or exponetial functions, but none of them fit the curve very well.

Can someone give some advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might help to have more information on where those curves come from. Knowing a bit about the context can help nail things down a lot.

Comment: If that is a vertical line then you can’t write it as a function

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the figure 1 of this [paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3093337.3037732). It's a curve about (SSD IOPS, latency)

Comment: @StevenCreech: In tropical geometry, you can :D

Answer (score 3):

Without information on the underlying phenomenon, it is indeed difficult to make precise guesses. As Andreas says, there seems to be a transition between two linear regimes.

A possible model is

$$y=\log(e^{ax}+e^b)+cx+d.$$

It realizes a smooth transition between the slopes $c$ and $a+c$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Woody3. I add a comment above to explain the origin of the curve. Could you give a approximate turning point of the curve? A initial parameters guess is helpful.

Comment: @zReagleLeung: the turning point is close to the intersection of the two asymptotes $y=b+cx+d$ and $y=ax+cx+d$. [Notice that I just replaced $b$ by $e^b$.]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have a try

Answer (score 2):

To me, these curves exhibit two linear regimes with a smooth transition. Denoting by $a_1x+b_1$ the first (left) linear form and by $a_2x+b_2$ the second (right) linear form and by $t$ the point, where the two linear forms meet, one could mimick such a behavior by the function
$$ f(x) = \frac{a_1x+b_1}{1+c^{x-t}} + \frac{a_2x+b_2}{1+c^{t-x}}, $$
where the exponential numerators serve as smooth step functions. The larger $c$, the sharper the transition. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v3oav6oya3) is a demonstration of how such a function looks like. For the dark blue curve, I heuristically [get](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0d3pmm2yuk) $a_1 \approx0.2, b_1\approx100,a_2 \approx100,b_2\approx-8.9\cdot10^4, t\approx900,c\approx1.7$.

In any case, for a rigorous fitting, it would be best to understand the origin of these curves.

Comment: The curve comes from a test on SSD, which is <IOPS vs latency>. It seems that the latency first grow slowly when IOPS is small, and quickly as IOPS reach the maximum.
Thank you Andreas. And where is the turning point approximately?  A initial parameters guess will help a lot when use curve fitting

Comment: @zReagleLeung: You can determine the two line parameters ($a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$) and their approximate intersection ($t$) from the graph by fitting the two linear functions. I have added the parameters for the dark blue curve.